# Clicking and dragging a Path2D line in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, drag, shapes

So, I am drawing a line using a Path2D and doing this:

```
Path2D linePath = new Path2D.Double();
linePath.moveTo(startingX, startingY);
linePath.lineTo(endingX, endingY);
repaint();
```

What I am trying to do is click-and-drag the line around. For right now, I don't want to **change** the line's structure (length, etc), I just want to move the line around. I know you can use `Path2D.contains(e.getPoint)` for *enclosed* shapes, but this doesn't work for lines. Any ideas? Thanks

**Full Code**

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Editor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Editor();
    }

    public Editor() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                            .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                        | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new UMLWindow();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class UMLWindow extends JFrame {

        Shapes shapeList = new Shapes();
        Panel panel;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public UMLWindow() {
            addMenus();
            panel = new Panel();
        }

        public void addMenus() {

            getContentPane().add(shapeList);

            setSize(300, 200);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JMenuItem lineMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New Line");
            lineMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("adding line");
                    shapeList.addLine();
                }
            });

            JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

            menubar.add(lineMenuItem);

            setJMenuBar(menubar);

            // shapeList.addLine();
        }
    }

    // Shapes class, used to draw the shapes on the panel
    // as well as implements the MouseListener for dragging
    public static class Shapes extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private List<Path2D> lines = new ArrayList<Path2D>();
        private Boolean drawing = false;
        private Point lineStartingPoint = new Point();
        private Point lineEndingPoint = new Point();
        private Path2D.Double linePath;

        public Shapes() {
            MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
            addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
            addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
        }

        public void addLine() {
            drawing = true;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            if (drawing) {
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                g2.drawLine(lineStartingPoint.x, lineStartingPoint.y,
                        lineEndingPoint.x, lineEndingPoint.y);
            }
            for (Path2D shape : lines) {
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.draw(shape);
            }
        }

        class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (drawing) {
                    lineStartingPoint = e.getPoint();
                    lineEndingPoint = lineStartingPoint;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (drawing) {
                    lineEndingPoint = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                    System.out.println(lines.size());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (drawing) {
                    drawLine(e);
                    drawing = false;
                }
            }

            public void drawLine(MouseEvent e) {
                drawing = false;
                lineEndingPoint = e.getPoint();
                linePath = new Path2D.Double();
                linePath.moveTo(lineStartingPoint.getX(),
                        lineStartingPoint.getY());
                linePath.lineTo(lineEndingPoint.getX(), lineEndingPoint.getY());
                lines.add(linePath);
                repaint();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could use `Path2D#getBounds#contains`

Comment: Hm...yes this is true actually, I can just move the bounds, right? I just want to be able to move the lines around. Eventually I will make it so that I can click-and-drag the end of one line and the end of the line will move/resize to where it is going

Comment: Essentially, all you're doing is changing the bounding box any way, it's just the visual representation that you seem to worried about.  Given the fact that you are only dealing with `Path2D`, you'd have to do a bunch of checking and casting to deal with all possible shapes...just saying ;)

Comment: Are you implying there is an easier way to implement it other than using Path2D? If so, I'm open to suggestions. I don't have to use Path2D, but I am using Path2D for other shapes and that is why I am using it now

Comment: So...I guess I could find the offset of the mouse point to the x,y of the bounds...then move the shape to new x,p + offset. I think.

Comment: Consider the bounding box as you "area of effect", you could even paint a little bounding box around the shape and put drag handles on it, like most graphics programs.  Then all you really care about is changing the bounding box...

Comment: Changing the bounding box to only be in effect over the line?

Comment: When the mouse is within the bounding box, then you could move the line, when the mouse is on the "drag" handles for the current shape, resize it...

Comment: Ah, yeah, I got that. But how can I sense that the line is over the actual line (not just the bounding box)? I only want to be able to drag if the cursor is directly (or close to directly) over the actual line

Comment: Do a search for "point does intersect line" and see why I'm suggesting not to.  The other problem is, you have no way to differentiate between a line, circle or rectangle...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63455/discussion-between-harry-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BasicStroke`

```
public Shape createStrokedShape(Shape s)
```

Define thickness of the line, pass your `Path2D` and obtain kind of outline of your path. Check whether the outline contains mouse position. If it's contains your mouse is over the `Path2D` and you can drag the Shape.